# Calculate Date with start date and number of days with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, datetime

I am trying to calculate a date from a start date and number of days, so basicly add the number of days to a start date and get an end date.  The issue is I get some strange results, but only on one date, I have been a few days now trying to figure this one out.

The function is:

```
CallculateDateFromDays = function(startDate, days) {
var policy_start_date_array = startDate.split("-");
var policy_start_date = new Date(policy_start_date_array[2], policy_start_date_array[1]-1, policy_start_date_array[0]);
var policy_start_date_add = new Date(policy_start_date.getTime() + ((days-1) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
var dateString = ("0" + (policy_start_date_add.getDate())).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (policy_start_date_add.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" + policy_start_date_add.getFullYear();
return dateString;}
```

The thing is it works until I use the date "28-10-2012" it gives me back the same date even if I add 2 days.

Any ideas, I am stumped.

Comment: What's the `(days-1)` good for?

Comment: Check out [date.js](http://datejs.com/). It has `date.add(n).days()` functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely your local timezone changes because of the end of the daylight saving time.

```
> new Date(2012, 9, 28)
Sun Oct 28 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200
> // 48 hours later:
> new Date(new Date(2012, 9, 28) + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
Mon Oct 29 2012 23:00:00 GMT+0100
```

Always use the UTC methods!

BTW, adding days is much more easier with `setDate`, which also works around timezone issues:

```
function calculateDateFromDays(startDate, days) {
    var datestrings = startDate.split("-"),
        date = new Date(+datestrings[2], datestrings[1]-1, +datestrings[0]);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return [("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2), ("0" + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2), date.getFullYear()].join("-");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am putting the string in "14-10-2012" and 1 day and I get back "18-02-2013", what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on UTC, I used it to fix my issue

Answer (score 2):

On October 28th the time changes from DST to "normal", so the day is not equal 24h. That may cause issues in your code.

Also why `(days-1) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`? If you set `days` to `1` the whole expression evaluates to zero...

Comment: because we use this to sell subscriptions by days and if you buy one day only it set the date to the same day

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way to achieve that : 
http://jsfiddle.net/pjambet/wZEFe/2/

Comment: he needs to start with a string, not a date object.

Comment: Try YYYY-mm-dd. The parser only parses that. But the problem is his date is in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript date format:

[How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date)

So you don't have to manually try to parse date strings.

Comment: Don't you think that `format` helper function does it manually, too?